# Inverting Web Mercator equations to convert pixels to latitude longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math

I am using equations for converting geographic points on earth to pixel coordinates, as explained in Daniel Shiffman's tutorial: https://gist.github.com/shiffman/a0d2fde31f571163c730ba0da4a01c82

That is:

```
function webMercX(lon, zoom) {
  lon = radians(lon);
  var w = 256; //width / 2;
  var a = (w / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = (lon + PI);
  var x = a * b;
  return x;
}

function webMercY(lat, zoom) {
  lat = radians(lat);
  var w = 256; //height / 2;
  var a = (w / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var c = tan(PI / 4 + lat / 2);
  var b = PI - log(c);
  var y = a * b;
  return y;
}
```

Based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator

Now, to implement accurate mouse interaction, I'm trying to do the opposite; convert pixels to Lat and Lon. I've managed to invert the first equation, so x to lon works well:

```
function inverseWebMercX(x,zoom) {
    var w = 256; //width / 2;
    var a = (w / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
    var b = x/a;
    var lon = b-PI;
    lon = degrees(lon);
    return lon;
}
```

This can be tested via

> inverseWebMercX(webMercX(10,2),2);

But I have so far failed to convert from y to lat, probably because I'm not solving the partial equations for var c and var lat right:

```
function inverseWebMercY(y,zoom) {
    var w = 256; //width / 2;
    var a = (w / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
    var b = y/a;
    var c = -(exp(b) + PI);
    var lat = (atan2(c) - (PI / 4))*2;
    lat = degrees(lat);
    return lat;
}
```

So, put simply, maybe someone with a better math's background knows how to solve these equations for lat and c respectively:

```
var c = tan(PI / 4 + lat / 2); 
var b = PI - log(c);
```

Appreciated

Comment: Doesn't the last comment in the gist you link above answer your question?

Comment: @barrycarter No, that's my own comment, asking the same question

Comment: @Kajuna Try `c = exp(PI - b)`.

Comment: @user3290797 Of course. How silly off me. Will make some tests, as I'm still seeing strange results sometimes, that was definitely wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3290797 found the cuplrit, and I had to change atan2() for atan(). This works well so far: (by the way, I use this within P5js, so that's why math functions look simpler than they should)

```
function inverseWebMercX(x,zoom) {
    var w = height / 2;
    var a = (w / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
    var b = x/a;
    var lon = b-PI;
    lon = degrees(lon);
    return lon;
}

function inverseWebMercY(y,zoom) {
  var w = height / 2;
  var a = (w / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = (y/a);
  var c = exp(PI-b);
  var lat = (atan(c) - (PI / 4))*2;
  lat = degrees(lat);
  return lat;
}
```